# CodeIgniter - AJAX pagination inside AJAX-generated element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a view that contains several sections which, when the document is ready, are populated with HTML fetched with the jQuery load() function. I'll spare the details of how the data is generated, unless it becomes necessary, but essentially it just returns a table of values from a series of database queries.

These sections are refreshed every ten seconds. In other words, every ten seconds, the html of those elements is replaced.

How could I implement pagination in these sections that retains the current page upon being refreshed?

Would I even use the CI Pagination class? Could I, or should I, rather just put in my own pagination links in and bind click event handlers to AJAX requests passing the page value as data and store the current page as a session variable?

Comment: dont use session for current page pass it as `GET`

Comment: @ArunKillu But when the section refreshes it needs to know what the current page is and the only way I can think of is to use session userdata.

Comment: You can store current page in Javascript variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden field to save current page.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Could you please elaborate on your answer?